# TCL- script to output a file which contains size of all the files in the directry and subdirectories

Tags: tcl

Please help me with the script which outputs the file that contains names of the files in subdirectories and its memory in bytes,  the arguement to the program is the folder path .output file should be file name in 1st column and its memory in second column

Note:folder contains subfolders...inside subfolders there are files

.I tried this way

```
set fp [open files_memory.txt w]
set file_names [glob ../design_data/*/*]
foreach file $file_names {
        puts $fp "$file    [lindex [exec du -sh $file] 0]"
}
close $fp
```

Result sample:

```
../design_data/def/ip2.def.gz    170M
../design_data/lef/tsmc13_10_5d.lef      7.1M
```

But i want only file name to be printed that is ip2.def.gz , tsmc13_10_5d.lef ..etc(not the entirepath) and file memorry should be aligned

TCL

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? (PS: StackOverflow is not a code writing service site) Hint: [`glob`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm) to get filenames, [`file`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm) to get the size.

Answer (score 1):

The **fileutil** package in Tcllib defines the command [`fileutil::find`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#12), which can recursively list the contents of a directory. You can then use `foreach` to iterate over the list and get the sizes of each of them with `file size`, before producing the output with `puts`, perhaps like this:

```
puts "$filename\t$size"
```

The `$filename` is the name of the file, and the `$size` is how large it is. You will have obtained these values earlier (i.e., in the line or two before!). The `\t` in the middle is turned into a TAB character. Replace with spaces or a comma or virtually anything else you like; your call.

---

To get just the last part of the filename, I'd do:

```
puts $fp "[file tail $file]    [file size $file]"
```

This does stuff with the full information about the file size, not the abbreviated form, so if you really want `4k` instead of `4096`, keep using that (slow) incantation with `exec du`. (If the consumer is a program, or a programmer, writing out the size in full is probably better.)

Comment: And no, we're not going to give you more detail than that _unless you show what you tried first_ because we're not a “write your code for you” service.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Donal's suggestion, there are more tools for getting files recursively:

- [`recursive_glob`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2042) (from the Tclx package) and
- [`for_recursive_glob`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2005) (also from Tclx)
- [`fileutil::findByPattern`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#13) (from the fileutil package)

Here is an example of how to use `for_recursive_glob`:

```
package require Tclx

for_recursive_glob filename {../design_data} {*} {
    puts $filename
}
```

This suggestion, in combination with Donal's should be enough for you to create a complete solution. Good luck.

## Discussion

- The `for_recursive_glob` command takes 4 arguments:

  1. The name of the variable representing the complete path name
  2. A list of directory to search for (e.g. `{/dir1 /dir2 /dir3}`)
  3. A list of patterns to search for (e.g. `{*.txt *.c *.cpp}`)
  4. Finally, the body of the for loop, where you want to do something with the filename.
- Based on my experience, `for_recursive_glob` cannot handle directories that you don't have permission to (i.e. on Mac, Linux, and BSD platforms, I don't know about Windows). In which case, the script will crash unless you `catch` the exception.
- The `recursive_glob` command is similar, but it returns a list of filenames instead of structuring in a for loop.